# How to modify the storage groups into standardized names when switching to Version 1.0.1 of Apache IoTDB?

Tags: database, apache-iotdb, iotdb

I previously used an older version (0.13.2) of Apache IoTDB, and my naming of some storage groups in this version was not very standardized. I now want to uniformly standardize and modify the name of these storage groups when upgrading to new version (1.0.1). I want know are there any convenient ways in IoTDB to change these names of storage groups? What are the steps that I need to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the TsFile API in Apache IoTDB to re-create the tsfile, and change the incompatible name and path to a compatible one, and then use `load tsfile` command to load your original data stored into the newer version of IoTDB.